# Plants that grow well in offices

Tags: indoors, plant-recommendations, office-gardening

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I grow in a sealed office environment with no natural light or airflow?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3837/what-can-i-grow-in-a-sealed-office-environment-with-no-natural-light-or-airflow)

Can anyone recommend a plant that do reasonably well in an office environment please?

The office is well lit but I am a good 10m away from any natural source of light.

Bonus points to something that would fruit or at least provide some colour.

Comment: This answer and the links are very similar and may be of assistance http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3837/what-can-i-grow-in-a-sealed-office-environment-with-no-natural-light-or-airflow?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm not quite sure how I missed that question.

Answer (score 3):

The other thread included a very good list, but I have one more to add - Zamioculcas, also called "ZZ plant". I have one at home that was about 5 feet from a window, and doing very poorly. I moved it to a corner that is about 20 feet from the window and gets no direct sun, and now it is thriving. Very hardy, likes to be neglected.

Comment: Good answer here is a link for more details http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zamioculcas I have seen more of these in interior landscapes the last few years so you should be able to find it at greenhouses and nurseries

Comment: That's a great suggestion Michelle, thanks.  It looks like you can pick these up from Ikea too. There's my Saturday morning sorted out!